# Makemigrations error : django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python, django

when I makemigrations

i get the following error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\KwanfahArunrerk\Desktop\Sinwattana_repo\trunk\sinwattana3_0\campaign\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sinUser.models import sinUser, sinUserCategories
  File "C:\Users\KwanfahArunrerk\Desktop\Sinwattana_repo\trunk\sinwattana3_0\sinUser\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from functionUtility.sendEmails import sendEmailFunctionIsError
  File "C:\Users\KwanfahArunrerk\Desktop\Sinwattana_repo\trunk\sinwattana3_0\functionUtility\sendEmails.py", line 12, in <module>
    HOSTNAME = Site.objects.get_current().domain
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 63, in get_current
    return self._get_site_by_id(site_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 35, in _get_site_by_id
    site = self.get(pk=site_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site
```

I am newbies python programming

some one can help me

thank you

Comment: Are you creating a fresh project ? Can you give the INSTALLED_APPS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `django.contrib.sites` in your INSTALLED_APPS and the run migrate command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: can you explain why this fixes the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Your `sendEmails` module has a query at the top level: `Site.objects.get_current()`. This is run when the module is imported, before migrations have had a chance to run.

You must not do any database actions at this level; put it into a method.

Comment: Ah, after a lot of searching, this answer pointed out the root cause!

Answer (score 3):

In this case some migrations are still pending so run `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`

Answer (score 1):

Change `"django.contrib.admin"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` to `"django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig"` and then run `makemigrations` command. after that you can revert your changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Worked for me, had pending migrations.