# Problem with migration after changing database in Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, migration

So i was using MySQL as database backend engine, and after changing it back to SQLite i can't make migrations. Tried removing migrations, and db.sqlite3 file but it's still not working. Console is showing me that error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: books_api_book
```

Old

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config.get("NAME"),
        'HOST': config.get("HOST"),
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': config.get("USER"),
        'PASSWORD': config.get("PASSWORD")
    }
}
```

New

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is some misconfiguration. Add database config to your question.

Comment: Added as you asked

Comment: check if all your migrations folder have  __init__.py file. Also you can check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664596/makemigrations-error-django-db-utils-operationalerror-no-such-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer. The problem was that in my models i had staticmethod that was values-list and getting all values from certain field. I commented it out, and it migrated normally.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try removing the files that are in your folder migration except `__init__.py`.

After that run :

```
py manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is an sqlite in your project directory then delete it. inside your migrations folder delete everything except ****init**.py.** and run **python manage.py makemigrations **AppName** and then migrate.